# Error while dropping table in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Error while using DROP TABLE command, after that it is throwing "FAILED: EXECUTION ERROR" for all other commands.

```
hive> show databases;
OK
default
practice_db
Time taken: 1.305 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
hive> use default;
OK
Time taken: 0.045 seconds
hive> show tables;
OK
tsunami_deathtoll
tsunami_hightoll
tsunami_japan
Time taken: 0.039 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
hive> drop table tsunami_Japan;
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:For direct MetaStore DB connections, we don't support retries at the client level.)
hive> show tables;
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10072]: Database does not exist: default
hive> show databases;
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:For direct MetaStore DB connections, we don't support retries at the client level.)
hive>
```

And it will work fine if I use "quit;" and start from the beginning and till "DROP TABLE" and again same..
**Note: table is MANAGED TABLE, using MySql as metastore, HIVE-1.2.2 version

Comment: **(1)** MANAGED /EXTERNAL does not seem relevant here. **(2)** Might be a MySQL connector issue.

Comment: "mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar" present in "$HIVE_HOME/lib/" path.

Comment: I have no idea, just a lead.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what went wrong. So I reinstalled Mysql (as I'm practicing) and copied updated Mysql connector jar (mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar) to hive lib path.

Now working fine.